# Lookup and lookupset functions in ssrs report mscrm

Tags: dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am using 1 dataset in my ssrs report and querying on phone call entity.I want to show Call From and Call To fields of phone call for that I have to use Lookup function in Call From and LookupSet function in Call To , But after using these expressions, I get multiple rows in the result. The expressions I am using are as follows-
Expression for Call From-

```
=IIF(Lookup(Fields!ae_partyid.Value,Fields!ae_partyid.Value,Fields!ae_participationtypemaskValue.Value=1,"DataSet1"),Fields!ae_partyid.Value,"")
```

Expression for Call To-

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Join(LookupSet(Fields!activityid.Value, Fields!activityid.Value, IIF(Fields!ae_participationtypemaskValue.Value = 2, Fields!ae_partyid.Value, ""), "DataSet1"), ",")),"",Join(LookupSet(Fields!activityid.Value, Fields!activityid.Value, IIF(Fields!ae_participationtypemaskValue.Value = 2, Fields!ae_partyid.Value, ""), "DataSet1"),", ").Trim(",").Trim())
```

Comment: `Lookup()` should be used for a 1:1 relationship. But it also can be used for a 1:n relationship, but then it retruns the first value it finds. `LookupSet()` is for a 1:n relationship and shows all the matches. So if your key from `Call To` exists multiple times the `LookupSet()` returns every pair for this key